# How to reconstruct sentences that have been split into lines?

Tags: pdf, nlp, ocr

This is a problem that comes up when extracting text from PDFs, OCR, and similar. I've been experimenting with PyMuPDF 1.22 to extract text from PDFs, and if I use ["block" mode](https://pymupdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/textpage.html#TextPage.extractBLOCKS) it is sometimes quite good; my question is general, not tool- or format-specific, however.

It seems if the PDF was made from latex (e.g. arxiv), or made with pandoc (via html), it will pull out headings and paragraphs as single blocks. There are `\n` but they are easy to strip out.

However if the pdf was exported from Word or OpenOffice, or if I am working with OCR, it seems each line becomes its own block. So I get text like:

```
The Big Heading
A Sub-Heading?
This is the first sentence and
now it ends. And a second sent-
ence begins and continues and
ends. A short third.
```

So it gives me 6 blocks, 6 strings. But if I wanted paragraphs I want 3 strings, and if I wanted sentences I want 5 strings, i.e this is the desired output:

```
The Big Heading
A Sub-Heading?
This is the first sentence and now it ends.
And a second sentence begins and continues and ends.
A short third.
```

Surely, turning lines into sentences must be a solved problem in OCR circles? But I'm not finding an established library or solution. I'm also wondering if there is a language-agnostic solution, or if it is done with language-specific heuristics (I'm usually not working with English text).

I can see a few heuristics:

- sentences that are notably shorter than the longest lines are headings (except when they aren't, like my last sentence above). (Also academic paper headings often stretch over two lines.)
- lines that end in "-" are sentences being continued (watch out for hyphenated words).
- a block with just "\n", can tell me a heading or paragraph just finished (but doesn't always happen).
- Sometimes headings are numbered "1. xxx" and "1.1. yyy".

But I don't want to re-invent the wheel, if this is already a solved problem.

----------_

**UPDATE:** I was reminded that there have been two shared tasks on sentence boundary detection in PDFs in the [FinNLP workshop](https://aclanthology.org/2020.finnlp-1.8/), the task summary paper of the second in 2020 is at https://aclanthology.org/2020.finnlp-1.8.pdf
All FinNLP workshop papers are at https://aclanthology.org/venues/finnlp/  (there doesn't seem to be a similar task in the 3rd, 4th and upcoming 5th workshops, despite far-from-perfect scores in the 2nd.)

Comment: @KJ My question is about what you do after the initial extraction, whether from pdftotext or mupdf or OCR: how you go from lines of text to sentences. (`pdftotext -layout` adds more whitespace, but is still outputting lines.)

Comment: @DarrenCook Are you only concerned about sentences? I do not think there is a solution out there, at least could not find one, so i'm building my own thing. The heuristics I use to merge are: same typesetting, hyphen, line lengths, distance between lines. In other words, you need more info than plain text can provide. Also note that you eventually will merge compound words (e.g. user-centric) if you look only at '-' at the end of the line. And when you venture into detecting paragraphs and dealing with bulleted list - that is another world of pain.

Answer (score 3):

This is not an answer, because I do not have the solution for your problem, but I hope it gives you something to consider and a bit cautions.

I do not think there is a solution out there for that. At least I did find it one, I'm building one myself.

I'm also more focused on reconstructing the original structure of the text, not only the sentences. So some of my point will not apply.

In my solution on not concerned with OCRed PDF, just normal PDF. And just English for now. Here are some considerations.

**Intro**

But let me start with the question.

*"Mr. & Mrs. Smith"*

How many sentences is that?  One if at all, but go explain that to computer. Every simple solution will get you 95% 'there' and then rest in just pure agony. It is like this with everything with PDF.

**Start with HTML.**

Or some other information reach format. You will need of the information you can get to get the text properly structured. The problem with PDFs is that they do not care about the semantics of the text. PDF is only concerned about layout, and there is no information about the structure of the text in PDFs. Only the position of there the line of chars should go. To know when to merge, you will need to know much more. Distance between lines, length of the line, paragraph intend, font & size.

**End of sentence punctuation**
For European languages, almost everything is uniform and clear, besides some freak-outs like Spanish questions marks ("¿Cómo estás?"), and the habit of placing end punctuations inside the quotation marks `"OK."` vs. `"OK".`.

Outside of the Western world ... [there be dragons](https://www.unicode.org/review/pr-23.html).

**Hyphenations**

Dehyphenation is relatively straightforward. If you see '-' at the end of the line, you can most certainly merge it with the next one. Except for the cased, there have compound words (e.g. user-centered) that just happened to separated. I think that the solution here is to look up in the same text for the same term to see how it is spelled in other places, or in a bigger corpus of text.
And of course, there are some edge cases, like German `ß` to `s-s` and `ck` to `k-k`.

**When to merge the lines**

First approximation: when the lines are set in the same font & size and 2 lines are nearby vertically and look for end punctuation is fitting.
You are 99% done. Then you will have only a couple of things to deal with:

- detect and ignore 'chrome elements': Page numbers, chapter titles
- detect if PDF has a 2-column layout and merge between columns
- merge between consequent pages
- list, which:

  - Often do not have end punctuations
  - the length of the line is unpredictable and indents are different from the rest of the text
- plus, some PDF have bullets is an image instead of a character and an added bonus.

**Paragraphs**

If you care about the structure of the text beyond sentences, detecting paragraphs can be a fun challenge to solve.

You are looking at the blobs of text, where lines have the similar spacing, set it same font size and the first line might either have an indent or a slightly larger top margin, and the last line is statistically shorter. All those signs are easy for humans to pick up, but algorithmically there is too much variability to have it error-free. The challenges are again related to ordered and bulleted lists because they might their own set of indents, often inverted. This especially true for academic papers, academics love their lists.

**Headings**

Again, basic heuristics like bigger font size and margins will get you to 90-95% success rate, and then you get docs where titles are set in the same font as the body but all caps and bold. Go figure.

**Languages**

Be ready to write custom parsers for some languages. Besides examples, I've mentioned above, think Chinese / Korean. I do not thing that they use '-' for hyphenation, or '.' for full stop, or letters for that matter. There is no one size fits all.

I hope this little rant gives you a bit of an idea of the challenges related to what you are asking for and why there is no solution for that yet.

Comment: Can you expand on hyphenation of ß - as it is a single glyph I would assume it never gets split up at end of sentence. E.g. can Maßband be broken up as any of "Ma- \n ßband", "Maß- \n band", "Maßba- \n nd", etc?

Comment: If the original spelling of the word contained ß as Grüße *it can be* hyphenated as Grüs-se not to Grü-ße. This is not a big deal because Grüsse is a valid spelling as well. Bigger problem is Zucker -> Zuk-ker, which was the case before the reform, but you still can see it old docs. see more https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/67554

Answer (score 0):

One approach, very fashionable nowadays, would be to train/fine-tune a large language model, such as [T5](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/model_doc/t5), on it. It is sequence to sequence (text of lines with \n in them, text string out with EOS in them), which is why I suggested T5, rather than BERT or GPL.

The training data is trivially easy to make. You start with any corpus that is already organised as headings and paragraphs (e.g. Wikipedia). You can then output it as lines to fit various screen widths in characters. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_wrap_and_word_wrap and https://www.unicode.org/reports/tr14/
(There is python implementation, see https://docs.python.org/3/library/textwrap.html)

I imagine it would be good to prepare a set of challenging paragraph sequences, as part of the training data, things like abbreviations and hyphenated words that end up at the end of the line, which might occur only rarely in a realistic corpus.

If you gathered the data, and trained enough, it is possible a single model could handle all languages and domains. It would need to be quite a large model to have that capacity, however.

The downside of this solution is that it can be much more demanding of hardware (memory, optional GPU), and slower, than if it is done heuristically.

I've also assumed all the information needed is available in a plain text input, which is debatable.