# Text Mining newspaper pdf in R?

Tags: r, pdf, text-mining, sentiment-analysis

I am trying to extract all the text from a PDF (a newspaper front page) in R with the following code:

```
library(pdftools)
text<-pdftools::pdf_text(pdf = "https://www.nytimes.com/images/2013/06/02/nytfrontpage/scan.pdf")
text<-gsub("\\n", " ", x1)     
text<-gsub(pattern="\\W", x1, replace=" ")
text<-stripWhitespace(x1)
```

But, this is not working due to the way the text is organized and other factors like many line breaks. This approach leads to **different articles and headlines being mismatched and stitched together**, rather than each being in a continuous format after the other.

For example, the headline "**US and China Will Hold Talks About Hacking**" instead becomes "**U.S. and China AS SYRIANS FIGHT, Will Hold Talks SECTARIAN STRIFE About Hacking**". Does anyone perhaps know how I might fix the code so that the mined text is in a more continuous format?

Comment: I've not found one pdf text extractor that follows any of the logical flow of text in columns like that, unfortunately.

Comment: The library `tabulizer` allows you to specify specific regions based on a coordinate grid to extract, which would allow you to break this into different segments. However, you'd have to manually specify the areas for each page, so it's not scaleable across many such articles.

Comment: I recently asked a similar - actually an easier - question, and haven't really come up with anything definitive yet, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76854854/how-to-reconstruct-sentences-that-have-been-split-into-lines.

Comment: You could train a deep learning tool (or similar computer vision/OCR tool) to detect the columns, which is a relatively easy task: easier than OCR-ing the whole page. You could then give those column coordinates to tabulizer (or muPDF has something similar - though no R bindings for that, it seems). I am still amazed that open-source tools to tie this all together don't already exist though.